# What is wrong with my iPhone's model number?

Tags: iphone

I just took a look at the reported model number on my iPhone 5c by going to Settings → General → About → Model. I am wondering, why does it says `NF155LL/A` instead of `MF155LL/A`?

`NF` model numbers shouldn't exist, right?

Comment: Are you seeing that stamped on the back of phone or in Settings > General > About?

Comment: Under the About Settings.  Model on the outside is A1532

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `N` in place of `M` simply means it's a replacement unit from Apple. As per [this](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models) wiki article:

> The first letter in the model number represents the source of the device. Currently, there are four known possible choices:
>
> - `F`: refurbished unit.
> - `M`: retail unit.
> - `N`: replacement unit.
> - `P`: personalized (engraved) unit.

You can [view the model number](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208200) for an iOS device by going to Settings → General → About → Model on your iPhone/iPad.

The default string displays the iOS device part number. Tapping on the model cell shows the model identifier string.

To identify an iPhone by its model number, refer to the Apple support article, [Identify your iPhone model](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201296)